# anyone can tell me about invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nokia'

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Here below is my model and form class:

```
class BOQ(models.Model):

    boq_amount =models.CharField(max_length=256)
    boq_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    boq_ver = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    po_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    po_type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    po_amount = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inv_amount =models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inv_number = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inv_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    site_accepted_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    pac_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    comments= models.TextField()
    client_data = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
      return self.comments


class BOQForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BOQ
        exclude = ('', 'client_data')
        fields = ('boq_amount', 'boq_date', 'boq_ver', 'po_number', 'po_date', 'po_type', 'po_amount', 'inv_amount','inv_number', 'inv_date', 'site_accepted_date', 'pac_date', 'comments')
```

The problem is that when i fill the form and submit it,the data is saved into database when go to django administration pannel and click on same record it will give the error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nokia'

[see this picture showing error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Qkt.png)

please anyone suggest me solution as early as possible for this who have resolve this kind of problem,i'm very thankfull to you if please..

Comment: What your `admin.py` looks like?

Comment: Why you have an empty string inside `exclude`???